# React Native Error While Running the App on virtual device Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found

Tags: react-native

I tried to run the command `npx react-native run-android` and got this problem :

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found`
`at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1469)`
`at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1477)`
`at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1315)`
`at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1277)`
`at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:709)`
`at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:243)`
`at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:172)`
`at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)`
`at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:251)`
`at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$900(Install.java:42)`
`at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:96)`
`at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:63)`
`at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:69)`
`at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:63)`
`at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:109)`
`at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:66)`
`error Failed to install the app.`

Although the Virtual Device is running but not able to install the app.